# Python call callback after async function is done

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to call a callback once a async function is done running

Here's an example of what im trying to do:

```py
import asyncio

async def asyncfunction():
    print('Hello')
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print('World')
    return 10

def callback(n):
    print(f'The async function returned: {n}')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# Will block the print until everything is done
callback(loop.run_until_complete(asyncfunction()))
print('Hey')
```

Here's what that does:

```
Hello
World
The async function returned: 10
Hey
```

And here's what I want it to do
Edit: The position of the 'Hey' doesn't really matter, as long as it doesn't have to wait for the async function to be done

```
Hello
Hey
World
The async function returned: 10
```

Edit: after some testing I have found a way that does what I want, although I don't know if its the best way to do it

```py
import asyncio
import threading

async def asyncfunction():
    print('Hello')
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print('World')
    return 10

def callback(n):
    print(f'The async function returned: {n}')

def wrapper(loop):
    callback(loop.run_until_complete(asyncfunction()))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
thr = threading.Thread(target=wrapper,args=(loop,))
thr.start()
print('Hey')
```

Comment: Move `print('Hey')` right after `print('Hello')`? It is brute force I know, but you have not talked about the logic of your desired output.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.add_done_callback

Comment: @mat, why do you think that your callback is a callback? Classical callback should be passed as an argument to a function, but it your code it is quite different.

Answer (score 5):

Using Threading with asyncio is just confusing and most likely not what you want. `run_until_complete` is one of the blocking call and should likely be the last statement in an `asyncio` program.

To add code after calling an async function, just create create a wrapper

```
async def myfunc():
  n = await asyncfunction()
  callback(n)

loop.run_until_complete(myfunc()) # from python 3.7, asyncio.run(myfunc())
```

---

If you just want to schedule some code to run asynchronously and continue with something else, create a task and await at the end

```
async def a_main():
  task = asyncio.ensure_future(myfunc()) # from python 3.7, asyncio.create_task(...)
  print("Hey")
  # Anything else to run
  await task # wait for the task to complete

loop.run_until_complete(a_main())
```

Answer (score 4):

DISCLAMER: `Following code creates different threads for each function.`

This might be useful for some of the cases as it is simpler to use. But know that it is not async but gives illusion of async using multiple threads, even though decorator suggests that.

To make any function non blocking, simply copy the decorator and decorate any function with a callback function as parameter. The callback function will receive the data returned from the function.

```
import asyncio
import requests


def run_async(callback):
    def inner(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            def __exec():
                out = func(*args, **kwargs)
                callback(out)
                return out

            return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, __exec)

        return wrapper

    return inner


def _callback(*args):
    print(args)


# Must provide a callback function, callback func will be executed after the func completes execution !!
@run_async(_callback)
def get(url):
    return requests.get(url)


get("https://google.com")
print("Non blocking code ran !!")
```

Comment: Glad to see you posting answers! I suggest adding some details about what you fixed or why it is right. It helps users understand what is going on, rather than just being served the a large code chunk as the answer. Consider it a rule for all your answers here. I hope you have a good time.

Comment: @Aman thanks buddy .. i will try my best to explain code in detail :)

Answer (score 2):

To get that order, you need to continue executing the coroutine after `print('Hey')`. You also need that `'Hey'` printed in the "lull" while `asyncfunction` is sleeping. That can essentially only be scheduled by the event loop itself; since `asyncfunction` is a black box for all you know and you don't know what it's waiting for or why or can get control back from it explicitly while it's sleeping.

So, execute both `asyncfunction` and `print('Hey')` as asynchronous tasks, and mostly *hope* that the scheduling works out so that 'Hey' is scheduled to run while `asyncfunction` is sleeping.

```
val, *_ = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
    asyncfunction(),
    asyncio.coroutine(print)('Hey')
))
callback(val)
```

`asyncio.coroutine(print)` turns `print` into an `async` function, and `gather` schedules both on the event loop simultaneously, and it will *probably* work out that `print` will be executed while `asyncfunction` is sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, along with **a tool function** named `run_with_callback`

```
# problem

async def asyncfunction(n):
    print(f'before sleep in asyncfunction({ n })')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print(f'after sleep in asyncfunction({ n })')
    return f'result of asyncfunction({ n })'

def callback(r):
    print(f'inside callback, got: {r}')


# straightforward solution

import asyncio

async def wrapper(n):
    r = await asyncfunction(n)
    callback(r)

asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(wrapper(1))
print('sync code following loop.create_task(1)')

asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(wrapper(2))
print('sync code following loop.create_task(2)')


# general solution with a tool function

def run_with_callback(co):
    def wrapper(callback):
        task = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(co)
        task.add_done_callback(lambda t: callback(t.result()))
        return callback
    return wrapper

# use as function

run_with_callback(asyncfunction(3))(callback)
print('sync code following loop.create_task(3)')

# use as decorator

@run_with_callback(asyncfunction(4))
def _tmp_callback_1(r):
    callback(r)
print('sync code following loop.create_task(4)')

# main

_all = asyncio.gather(*asyncio.all_tasks(asyncio.get_event_loop()))
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(_all)
```